# VLC - How to stream with VLM config?

Tags: stream, vlc, rtp

In our project, we use VLC to stream a video multicast (we use RTP protocol).
We have two stream: a High Quality and Low quality.

We have generate VLM config with vlc:

```
# VLC media player VLM command batch
# http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

new Stream HQ broadcast enabled loop
setup Stream HQ input "file:///E:/test/1.mp4"
setup Stream HQ output #rtp{dst=224.0.0.1,port=5004,mux=ts}
setup Stream HQ option file-caching=300
setup Stream HQ option file-caching=300
setup Stream HQ option file-caching=300
setup Stream HQ option file-caching=300

new Stream LQ broadcast enabled loop
setup Stream LQ input "file:///E:/test/1.mp4"
setup Stream LQ output #transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Auto,width=400,height=244,acodec=mp3,ab=64,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:rtp{dst=224.0.0.2,port=5004,mux=ts}
setup Stream LQ option file-caching=300
setup Stream LQ option file-caching=300
setup Stream LQ option file-caching=300
```

Question 1:
We would like run VLM with VLC. So we use this command
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --vlm-conf=vlcConfig.vlm -I dummy
but stream doesn't work. With VLM GUI streams work.

Question 2:
Can we use "adaptative bitrate" to have only one stream ? (auto quality depending brandwidth)

Question 3:
For example in Stream HQ we stream only one video. Now, We would like stream a playlist video. Idea how do this ?